# Большой массив / Си

Tags: c

Программа падает при запуске. Массив очень большой, наверно, но он мне нужен. Как быть?

```
void main() {
    int arr[1002][2001];
}
```

Comment: > Массив очень большой, наверно, но он мне нужен.

Пускай int это 4 байта: 8 миллионов байт, 8 мегабайт - должно работать без особых проблем.

> Программа падает при запуске.

Что говорит gdb? Как именно падает?

---
upd Вообще-то main должна возвращать int, свидетельствующий о статусе выполнения программы.

---
upd2 а ну-ка еще раз про 7.6 гигабайт и "не умеет считать", пожалуйста, я не успел почитать

Comment: товарищ, только что громогласно заявивший про неумение считать а что эже вы так скромно удалили свой весьма компетентный ответ? Несолидно как-то

Comment: @Fike, "Вообще-то main должна возвращать int, свидетельствующий о статусе выполнения программы" -- в С99 и С++ возращать из main необязательно, по умолчанию возвращается 0.

Comment: @dzhioev, да я понимаю, что компилятор не пропустил бы неверное объявление (хоть и не знал, что именно в стандарте прописано), я про то что так делать явно не стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

По всей видимости у Вас в программе происходит переполнение стека.

Если размер `int` у Вас 4 байта, то всего массив занимает 4 * 1002 * 2001 = 8 020 008 байт, в то время как размер стека по умолчанию 2^16 = 65536 байт!

Чтобы решить Вашу проблему Вам необходимо выделять память под массив не на стеке, а в динамической "куче". Для выделения блока памяти вы можете использовать функции `calloc` или `malloc` из стандартной библиотеки, для очистки `free`.

Более подробно про использование этих функций и управлением памятью Вы можете прочитать в любом учебнике по Си или в интернете.

Желаю успехов!

UPD: вот [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/131713/) очень хорошо написано про стековую память - может Вам пригодится)

Comment: Не обязательно динамически, можно и глобально.

Comment: @progzdeveloper, стек 64 Килобайта -- это Вы, видимо ДОС имеете в виду?

Comment: посмотрел у себя - 8мб под стек. Видимо очень древние данные у @progzdeveloper :).

для тех, кто хочет узнать на своей машине размер стека (linux way) - нужно запустить в консоли `ulimit -a`. Там много чего ещё интересного будет.

Comment: Ну может с 64K я и поторопился, но под Мастдаем 1M по умолчанию точно:
 `For ARM, x86 and x64 machines, the default stack size is 1 MB.`
Взято отсюда: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx

Answer (score 2):

очевидно, вы своим далеко не самым маленьким массивом просто переполняет стек. используйте динамическое выделение памяти с помощью new:

```
int** arr = new int*[1002];
for(int i = 0; i < 1002; ++i)
    arr[i] = new int[2001];
```

также я бы на вашем месте не стал пренебрегать использованием стандартных контейнеров например vector. это более разумное решение, нежели ковыряться с указателями

Comment: @DreamChild, я так понимаю, что автору нужен чистый си, поэтому с векторами не получится.

Comment: @Fike пусть так, в таком случае для этого подойдет первая часть ответа

Answer (score 0):

Да,это банальное переполнение,программа просто выходит за рамки возможного и закрывается.Нужно выделить динамическую память,но с предыдущим комментарием не согласен,если программа на чистом Си,то как я понял new это оператор выделения динамической памяти в С++, в Си такого оператора нет и будет еще одна очередная ошибка.В данном случае вам нужно использовать функции calloc\malloc.